# Combining two regex "^[\x20-\x7E]*$" and "\S(.*\S" into one

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two regex that work separately: `^[\x20-\x7E]*$` and `\S(.*\S`

But I don't get how to combine the two so it will match them both.

I tried `(^[\x20-\x7E]*$)*?(\S(.*\S)?)` but it didn't work.

I used this in input tag with `pattern="(^[\x20-\x7E]*$)*?(\S(.*\S)?)"`

Comment: Can we get an example of text that you want to match and text that you do not, just to make testing our solutions to help you easier? Thanks!

Comment: `\S(.\S` doesn't look like a valid JS regex to me

Comment: It looks like that was a typo @CristianTraìna, the other instances all say `\S(.*\S`

Comment: @Aaron Meese
I have to match all alphanumeric with special characters except characters like á (Latin characters) . also avoid starting space and  ending space but should be match with in between spaces eg to match, "Priya@ #432"   eg to do not match  "  priya##23á   "

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two regexes with the pipe symbol. It is the same as the logical OR. Here's a code snippet demonstrating how to use this.

```
import re

regex_list = ["^[\x20-\x7E]$", "\S(.*\S)"]
regex = '|'.join(regex_list)

print(regex)                       # ^[ -~]$|\S(.*\S)
print(re.search(regex, "C"))       #matches first pattern
print(re.search(regex, "CAT CAT")) #matches second pattern
print(re.search(regex, " 3 "))     #matches neither pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use word boundaries (`\b`) instead of the `\S` anchor:

```
^\b[\x20-\x7E]*\b$
```

This would match your given test case `Priya@ #432`, but would not match `priya##23á` or `Priya@ #432` . You can see an example of this regex in action on Regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/bpcUmQ/1).